# Can someone help me with this class

Tags: python, class, oop, object, methods

```
class database(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []


    def insert(self, e):
        for i in range[len(self.l)]:
            if i == e: return
        self.l.append(e)
```

Why is insert giving me an unbound method can someone help?

Comment: `range[len(self.l)]` should be `range(len(self.l))`. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: @Haidro Make it an answer.

Comment: @Haidro got the point, but Python does not raise an unbound method exception. Maybe he's calling the method without initializing the object.

Comment: I've said it before, but almost every time you find yourself writing `for i in range(len(whatever))`, you are probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop there, you can just do this:

```
def insert(self, e):
    if e not in self.l:
        self.l.append(e)
```

Or, if you just want to make sure there are no duplicates; use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), which is an *unordered* collection of unique items; and you can't have duplicates in it:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(1)
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s.add(1) # Note, no error message on duplicate
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
set([1, 2, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because of your typo:

```
range[len(self.l)]
```

Should be

```
range(len(self.l))
```

You use parentheses `()` for calling functions. Brackets `[]` are used for lists and other features such as slicing.